# Python Syntax : How do I check if a value(string) is a String or a number and then do something

Tags: python

Java guy moving to Python.

I would like to check if a string is a string or number and then do something. I am getting error with this syntax

```
if value.isdigit() == True
 do something

else:
    if value.isdigit == False
       do something.
```

Comment: whats the error?

Comment: This works fine: 

`if value.isdigit(): print("A digit") else:print("Not a digit")`

Comment: A string is always a string, not a number. You don't need any code to check that. If you want to check whether you can call `int` or `float` on a string to produce an int or float, just call it and catch the exception if it turns out you can't. (That's a normal thing to do in Python.) `isdigit` won't tell you what you need to know; for example, it rejects `-` signs.

Comment: A number can be `int` or `float`. `str.isdigit()` or `str.isalnum()` will return `False` with strings having floats formats. So, you have an idea about your strings ? or you need something general ? Otherwise, a string is ALWAYS a string :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the nested `if` statement and explicit boolean comparisons. Also, don't forget to use `value.isdigit()` instead of `value.isdigit`, and make sure you include colons at the end of `if ...`.

```
if value.isdigit():
    # only digits
else:
    # not only digits
```

Comment: I removed the explicit booleans and things worked. Thanks @gyre and all for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your error was but you missed the colons after the two if statements. And if you wanted to check if the string is alphabetical or a number, you can use the `.isalnum` method which stands for is alphanumeric.

```
if value.isalnum():
    # do stuff
else:
    # if it contains stuff not alphanumeric
```

Other method includes `isalpha`, `isdigit`, `isdecimal`, `isidenitifier`, `islower`, and many more...

Comment: A string is always a string.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga haha now it sounds silly, just wrote it according to the title

Answer (score 0):

As some one mentioned in the comments it is perfectly acceptable in Python to take it from the horse's mouth:

```
try:
    complex(x)    # should be the most general
    result = True # Python has no objections
except ValueError:
    result = False
```

This will recognise anything from `-1_000_000` (Python3.6+ only) to `+.24E-2+j`. Only exception (I believe): It will not accept binary, octal or hex literals (`0b1001`, `0o77`, `0xff`) If you want to allow those you need to special case.

Alternatively, if you are a regexp wizard, there is the `re` module. I'm not but here is an attempt at an integer detector:

```
import re
int_pattern = re.compile('^[+-]?(?:0|(?:[1-9][0-9]*))$')

int_pattern.match('-13')
# <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='-13'>
```